# Use 2 Application extended android project as library

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

I need to include 2 Android projects extending `Application` class as library project in my project. Android manifest allows to make only 1 `android:name=` in manifest file.

Please advice me the best practice to get it done.

Looking forward for tips & Suggestions.

rohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I got it work. What I did is let the `android:name=` as it is in `Application` of `AndroidManifest.xml` and in the other application, i used `getApplication()` of `Activity`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()